# Use QQplot to check if data fits exponential distribution

Tags: r, qq-plot

I have a dataset which contains about 10000 numbers(class numeric), I want to use QQ plot to see if the data fits the exponential distribution.

This is what I did

```
plot(qexp(ppoints(length(data))),data)
```

and by observation to determine if the exp distribution fits.

Am I right about this?

Comment: In general, they're not even going to be in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work unless your data are sorted.

This works:

```
plot(qexp(ppoints(length(data)))[order(order(data))],data)
```

(that's essentially what `stats:::qnorm.default` does to get the two variables in the same order)

There's also an example (the third last one, relating to a chi-square with 3 df) in the help for `stats::qqplot` that you can easily adapt.

(Also, don't call your data `data`.)

Comment: Hi Glen, is there an equivalent function for a Gumbel distribution instead of an exponential distribution? Say if I want to use QQplot to check if data fits Gumbel distribution instead?

Comment: just replace qexp with the quantile function for the  standard Gumbel. $\:\:$ $\:\:$ $\:\:$  `qgumbel = function(x) -log(-log(x))`. .... or call an equivalent function from one of the R packages that implements the Gumbel r,d,p,q functions

Answer (score 1):

`qqplot` will sort the points for you.  So you can just call

`qqplot(qexp(ppoints(length(data))), data)`

Comment: I like the simplicity of this

Comment: Hi Adam, is there an equivalent function for a Gumbel distribution instead of an exponential distribution? Say if I want to use QQplot to check if data fits Gumbel distribution instead?